# Help with the integral $\int_{-b/2}^{\frac{\pi-10b}{20}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+bx+c}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $b$ and $c$ satisfy the equation $4c-b^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{100}$, then how should I solve the integral:

$I =\int_{-b/2}^{\frac{\pi-10b}{20}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+bx+c}$

All I know is that the integral is supposed to be an integer, but I'm puzzled as to how I am supposed to even approach this integral.

edit: The answer is 5. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $b^{2}-4c<0$, so the quadratic has no real roots. Complete the square on the denominator, and fiddle around with the constants (with a substitution) until you get something that resembles $$\int \frac{1}{x^{2}+1}=\tan^{-1}(x)+C$$

Comment: thx boy, you the real mvp

Answer (score 1):

we get $x^2+2\frac{b}{2}x+\frac{b^2}{4}+c-\frac{b^2}{4}=\left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2+\frac{4c-b^2}{4}$ now you can put $4c-b^2=\frac{\pi^2}{100}$ in this equation